# Is there such a thing as a free command line application for Windows which will translate English to Spanish/French etc. without network connections?

Tags: windows, gratis, translation, english

I'm not looking for an "API", free or not. Not a service, not something which has to in any way contact the outside world. I want a single application with every freely available dictionary/data they could find packed into a big ol' EXE which I can then send strings in English and get back translated into German, Spanish, French or more languages. (The more, the better, of course.)

Also, plus points if it can translate them back into English as well.

Since even the commercial APIs that exist seem awfully bad, created and maintained by companies with so much money that most of us cannot even comprehend the sums, I *highly* doubt that "some dude" has created such a thing which actually works in any meaningful manner and then gives it away for free.

Nevertheless, what am I supposed to do when I don't have any money and I need such a thing? The reason I cannot use APIs is for privacy reasons and because they always have narrow limits and try to "upsell" you to a non-free account.